# Memcache add key to specific memcached server

Tags: php, memcached

I have add two memcached servers to my web app with the following code:

```
    $servers = array(
      array('xxx.xxx.xxx.185', 11211),
      array('xxx.xxx.xxx.10', 11211)
    );
    global $m;
    $m = new Memcached('persistant-id');
    if (0 == count($m->getServerList())) {
        error_log("add memcache servers num: " . count($m->getServerList()));
        return $m->addServers($servers);
    }
```

I want to add the key/values to specific server. 
How can I add a specific key for example to xxx.xxx.xxx.185 server?

I wonder in the web and find the `addByKey($serverKey, $key, $value, $expiration = null)` but I can't find what is  the $serverKey.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pick a specific server by ip to store the data on when using a pooled connection (I could be wrong, but haven't seen anything to the contrary).  It's my understanding in the *ByKey() functions, the `$serverKey` is just an arbitrary grouping you can assign.  You are not picking which server the data is stored on, only specifying that you want all items added with that `$serverKey` to end up on the same server.

The only sure fire way I know of to guarantee data ends up on a specific server would be to create the connection and only add the data to that specific server.

A less than ideal alternative suggestion I can think of trying (which I have no idea if it would work, and is purely a hypothesis), would be create a connection to just the `xxx.185` server, add a single item with whatever `$serverKey` you want, then create a pooled connection, add a bunch of items using that same `$serverKey`, and then use the `getServerByKey()` method to see if all the data you added all ended up on the same server.

If so, you would just have to seed the server you want with all the `$serverKey`'s you use.

If both servers show up, then the `$serverKey` might be specific to the connection and not the available data set.

But this is not an ideal solution, particularly with the volatility of the memcached data, if this works at all (Like I said, never tried it, it's purely a guess).  You'd have to re-seed the server every time your memcached restarts or all the data with that `$serverKey` is discarded for more room

Hope that helps